# MySQL 8 unusual behavior

Tags: mysql, mysql8

The project that I'm working on using database frequently and does heavy procedures.

I'm always monitoring the system. with 16GB of RAM and 8 CPU's system usually works fine and not reaching it's limits but MySQL goes away very frequently with different errors:

[image]

Here is MySQL 8 configuration

```
   [mysqld]
    sql_mode=""
    pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
    log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
    log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
    join_buffer_size = 256M
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G
    innodb_log_file_size=4G
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances=12
    expire_logs_days=3
    long_query_time=5
    innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100
```

How can I prevent this? What am I doing wrong?

Here is error log: https://gist.github.com/turalus/d581b46f349aa815ab49f486605c0061

Answer (score 0):

> The table 'UserKeyword' is full!

Check disk space.

> unknown variable 'query_cache_size=0'.

That setting (and similar settings) have been removed from MySQL 8.  Are you using an old my.cnf?  Remove references to `query_cache...` from the config.

> Do you already have another mysqld server running with Mysqlx ?'

Perhaps two instances are running?

> innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G

Not if RAM is 16GB.  Change the setting to 10G.